# Redirecting Output and Error to custom PSHostUserInterface

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using a custom `PSHostUserInterface` to handle custom input and output when running PowerShell scripts. By default, it seems that `Write-Error` does not use `PSHostUserInterface.WriteErrorLine`, and `Write-Output` does not use any of the available functions.

The common answer seems to be using `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine()` instead of `Write-Error`, but I have a large collection of existing scripts and would prefer not to have to go though and edit all of them. I would like to, if at all possible, redirect error messages such that the message from `Write-Error "message"` is passed as `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine("message")`. Is this possible?

In addition to this, I would like to be able to also redirect `Write-Output` to `PSHostUserInterface.WriteLine`. To make matters a bit simpler, all calls to `Write-Output` are strings, so although a `PSObject` is spawned when it is called, it is guaranteed to only be a string.

I realize this may not be the best practice, but all of the scripts in question (and there are many of them) are in-house and use the basic `Write-*` syntax, so keeping the scripts as-is is much preferred to changing all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite Write-Error function. You can put new definition at the beginning of each script or save it as a module to apply new definition across all scripts

```
function write-error {param($errMsg)
$host.ui.WriteErrorLine($errMsg)
}
```

To invoke original Write-Error cmdlet you can use

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error
```